# OpenSSL in Erlang/RabbitMQ does not create the SSLKEYLOGFILE

Tags: openssl, rabbitmq, tls1.3

I use RabbitMQ 3.10.6 with Erlang 25.0 and TLS 1.3 under Windows 10.

I set SSLKEYLOGFILE as a global environment variable and would expect an appropriate output about TLS connection creation. But when I start RabbitMQ and the clients connect with it I see no output in the defined key log file. When I open Edge with an https connection I see some output though.
So far as I have read Erlang 25.0 comes with at least OpenSSL 1.1.1 which supports the SSLKEYLOGFILE variable.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: **OpenSSL does not support _envvar_ SSLKEYLOGFILE**;1.1.1 up provides an _API_ (specifically a callback) that allows _application code_ to support it or an equivalent, but I have no idea if/how Erlang does.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 no, Erlang does not use `SSL_CTX_set_keylog_callback` anywhere in its source code.